# "bokeh serve --show myapp.py" returns invlaid syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have read about bokeh and decided to give it a shot as I thought it would work well for my purposes. I am just trying to test currently, trying to just get an app to run. However, every time I try to run the simple app with `bokeh serve --show myapp.py` I receive a syntax error, "invalid syntax". I don't know if it matters, but I have tried running this from Spyder (Python 3.5) as well a from python.exe to no avail. I am on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Here's the simple app:

```
from bokeh.models import widgets
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox

tbox = widgets.inputs.TextInput()

layout = column(widgetbox(tbox))

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Why would I receive a syntax error from this statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

needs to be run in a command prompt and not in a python console

You can use (in python) show(layout) or show(plot) etc... to test one part of the document **but that wont actually** launch an app with python function call backs and updating etc...

Comment: Yes, I used that, and every other document I found online that tells you to do that same thing. The problem is that it doesn't work for me, and none of the documents state how to fix it. Is there a specific directory the command prompt needs to be pointed to in order for this to run?

Comment: If you are running it from the .py  file, change directory to the same directory myapp.py is in. And did you run the command from the command prompt? or try minGW or similar.